# How to check security and other updates avaliable on linux distro automaticaly?

Tags: linux, patching, vulnerability-management

Let suppose we have network of 10 plus Linux machines having different distro (debian, Centos , Redhat and Arch etc ).

Can we implement some  centralized system where we have update about update on all of these machines(there could be security , application  or Linux kernel updates).

So we can patch vulnerabilities timely and mitigate intrusion threat.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is creating an apt-get/yum respository for each of the unique distros you have installed.  I don't believe there is a way to do this across distributions.  You would then want to have a cronjob on each machine regularly check for updates against these repos.

Comment: Most big distros have a standard procedure for issuing security announcements publicly for interested parties, typically in the form of a special mailing list.  Your best bet is to sign up for those.

Comment: Why is `security-theater` tagged here?

Comment: @multithr3at3d thank for pointing, my bad , I have updated tag list. Thanks